# GRUB acting strange when booting with multiple hard drives

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, uefi, grub-efi

I have a dual boot (Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04 LTS) on my laptop. I recently installed a new SSD in my laptop. I was expecting to need to replace the old one, so I cloned the old drive onto the new one before I opened my laptop. However, when I opened up my laptop, I was greeted by an empty drive slot, so I installed it there.

However, the problem is that GRUB doesn't seem to know what to do with two bootable SSDs. When attempting to boot into the old drive's copy of Ubuntu, it seems to randomly choose whether to boot into the old drive or the new drive. When attempting to boot into the old drive's copy of Windows, it boots using the new drive as C. When attempting to boot into the new drive's copy of Windows, an error occurs.

I would like to use my old drive to hold the operating systems and the new one as a shared data drive.

I do not have a Windows install medium, as Windows came preinstalled with my laptop, and I would like to avoid shelling out the extra cash to get one if possible.

I am unsure of what logs I need to provide, so leave a comment and I will add them as necessary with edits.

Comment: Ubuntu 20?  There is no such release. Ubuntu uses *yy.mm* format (year.month of release) for all server & desktop releases, the *yy* being used only for IoT and specialist appliance/device releases (also suitable for cloud use) that can use *snap* packages only.  By Ubuntu 20 do you mean Ubuntu Core 20?  as it's a different product to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (desktop or server).

Comment: If you cloned the root partition, both copies will have the same UUID. That will baffle grub. Change the UUID on one of them.

Comment: @OrganicMarble That is likely the cause of some of my issues. Would you mind pointing me in the right direction of how to go about doing that?

Comment: Some more info is needed. Please edit your question to include the full text of `/etc/default/grub`, and  the output of `sudo blkid`.

Comment: Windows has your product key embedded in UEFI. So you reinstall from standard Windows ISO. But usually have to have vendors drivers added separately. May be a hassle, so create good Windows backup. And a Windows repair/recovery flash drive from within Windows. Usually easier to just install Ubuntu & restore from your normal backup. You have to change UUID in every partition, and change UUID in all places, grub, fstab and maybe others to match new UUID you create. Or install easier.